# In decorated tf function, I get error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I've looked all over but can't find anyone who's previous answers help.

I have a tensorflow model with an @tf.function in it that does the training (tf version 2.3.0). Within the train_step call, I need to pass the data from a tensor on to a numpy function that performs a cwt transform on it. There is (afaik) no tensorflow cwt, thus the need to pass this on to a numpy function. The issue I have is that within the @tf.function, the tensors are graphed, and thus one cannot directly call .numpy() to transform that tensor into a numpy array. Small code snippet shows the code, below.

My question is how can I transform my generated output data from my generator call into something I can pass on to this numpy function. Here's hoping there's a way to do this!

Thanks.

```
@tf.function
def train_step(self, true_data):
    noise = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1, 100, 1], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32) 
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        generated_data = self.generator(noise)
        nump_data = generated_data.numpy()

<this line produces: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'>
```

Comment: Have you run your graph?

Comment: Is there a quick way to do this? I'm coming over from PyTorch, so my understanding of Tensorflow is still not up to snuff. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I really know nothing about either except hearsay and some broad conceptual stuff. My understanding is that a tensor will only have a numpy value after all of its dependencies have been evaluated in a session. You may want to search the docs on this one.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, as per `tf.function` rules you can not use `.numpy()` functions inside `tf.fucntion`.
There is still some workaround you can do to convert **Tensor to a NumPy array** when graph mode is enabled using `eval()`.

Below is the modified code which should help your cause.

```
@tf.function
def train_step(self, true_data):
    noise = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1, 100, 1], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32) 
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        generated_data = self.generator(noise)
        nump_data = generated_data.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
```

If the `tf.function` is not necessary for your code, you can directly run it with `eager execution enabled` instead of `graph mode` with your `Tensorflow 2.3 version` which enables eager execution by default. That will avoid these issues.